# R + convert a list of results into data frame

Tags: r, dataframe, lapply

I am working on multiple csv files in one go.

```
getResult<-function(df){
  c(runif(1, 0, 1), runif(1, 0, 1))
}

filenames <- list.files("temp", pattern="*.csv", full.names=TRUE)
ldf <- lapply(filenames, read.csv)
res <- lapply(ldf, getResult)
```

In 'getResult' function I am calculation two float values. Finally I need a data frame with filenames and the two 'float' values. How do I do that?

I tried doing the following:

```
data.frame(res,filenames)
```

But I don't get the desired result. Can someone guide?

Thanks.

Adding partial dput(res) output:

```
list(c(0, 0.11340206185567), c(0, 0.0317919075144509), 
c(0, 0.0569948186528497))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `sapply()` instead of `lapply()` to calculate `res`. This will make matrix with two rows and columns corresponding to number of files. Then in `data.frame()` use `t()` to transpose your matrix to two columns.

```
res <- sapply(ldf, getResult)
data.frame(t(res),filenames)
```

Comment: I liked this answer more as it doesn't convert the result into string. The other answer is converting the result into string.

Answer (score 3):

You can try following

```
data.frame(do.call(rbind, res), filenames)
```

`do.call` will call `rbind` function over list `res` and then `data.frame` will bind the columns into a `data.frame`